# Php Time Format

Tags: php, mysql

I have here a mysql query that get the average of the column(the column data type is 'time'). The column values for example are:
00:00:55, 00:00:59, 00:01:03

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(column_name)) FROM table_name)AS average_result
```

In my Php I formatted the result this way:

```
<?php foreach($display_average as $da){
     echo date("H:i:s", ($da["average_result"]));
}
?>
```

Outputs: 08:00:59 instead of 00:00:59, Why does this starts with 08? Or did I miss something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both PHP's date/time functions and MySQL's date/time data types handle **wall clock timestamps**, not **durations**; i.e. `00:00:55` means *fifty-five seconds past midnight*. This is not what you want; you couldn't handle *durations* longer than 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds, because the data types and functions you're using are handling clock time, which cannot exceed these values.

Your specific issue stems from timezone settings. Your larger issue is that you need to store simple integer values expressing elapsed seconds or minutes; not timestamps. To format that into a human readable string in PHP you can use the [`DateInterval` class](http://php.net/DateInterval).

Answer (score 0):

see [php manul](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), about the `date_default_timezone_set` your timezone is +8

the default `date.timezone` of PHP is utc, u can change it to `date.timezone = PRC`

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("H:i:s", 59);//00:00:59

//date_default_timezone_set('RPC');
//echo date("H:i:s", 59);//08:00:59
```

Comment: I actually uses Codeigniter as my framework so how should I do this?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');//before u call date()

Comment: Got it man ! Many thanks ! I just add it in my outsidemost index.php file so this would be globally available in my whole project.

Comment: @Kentot you should double check deceze's answer

Answer (score 0):

Always go for standard/formal approaches. But if anyhow you need it custom, then you can do almost everything with programming. Here we go

Get your time as numbers (number of seconds in your time filed) from database as

```
SELECT 
AVG
(
    HOUR(column_name) * 3600
    + MINUTE(column_name) * 60
    + SECOND(column_name)
) AS numeric_average_result FROM table_name
```

Now you can convert number of seconds to proper time as

```
foreach($display_average as $da)
{
    $r = numToTime($da["numeric_average_result"]);
    echo "<br>".$r;
}


function numToTime($num)
{
    $seconds = $num%60;
    $num = (int)($num/60);
    $minutes = $num%60;
    $hours = (int)($num/60);
    return make2digit($hours).":".make2digit($minutes).":".make2digit($seconds);
}

function make2digit($val)
{
    if(strlen($val) == 1)
       return "0".$val;
    else
       return $val;
}
```