# Converting minutes to hours issue in php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
 $total_days = 0;
 $minutes = 1200;
 echo date('H:i', mktime(0, $minutes));
```

This return me 20 hours, which means two 8 hours  + 4 hours working day. It means that in the `$total_days` will have 2 days + 4 h. How can I divide the 1200 minutes to get 2 days  and 4 hours ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30232075/476 for why you should not use time-related functions for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate it manually -

```
$minutes = 1200;

$total_hours = $minutes / 60;

echo floor($total_hours / 8). ' days ' . ($total_hours % 8). ' hours';
```

**Output**

```
2 days 4 hours
```

`$total_hours` contains fractinal value then the calculation should be changed accordingly.